# Coding in python with a namedtuple using sort

Tags: python, sorting, namedtuple

Write a sequence of statements that prints out the list of Restaurants RC in order from least expensive to most expensive (best dish). it should use the sort(), and key=restaurant_price as an argument to sort()

Given this code:

```
from collections import namedtuple 
Restaurant = namedtuple('Restaurant', 'name cuisine phone dish price')
RC = [
    Restaurant("Thai Dishes", "Thai", "334-4433", "Mee Krob", 12.50),
    Restaurant("Nobu", "Japanese", "335-4433", "Natto Temaki", 5.50),
    Restaurant("Nonna", "Italian", "355-4433", "Stracotto", 25.50)]

def restaurant_price (restaurant:Restaurant)-> float:
    return restaurant.price
```

I wrote:

```
print(sort(RC,key=restaurant_price()))
```

My code gets an error statement of "name 'sort' is not defined"

Answer (score 4):

`sort` is an inplace method that operates on the original list and returns None, you can use sorted:

```
print(sorted(RC,key=restaurant_price)) # creates new list
```

Using sorted:

```
In [23]: sorted(RC,key=restaurant_price)
Out[23]: 
[Restaurant(name='Nobu', cuisine='Japanese', phone='335-4433', dish='Natto Temaki', price=5.5),
 Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', dish='Mee Krob', price=12.5),
 Restaurant(name='Nonna', cuisine='Italian', phone='355-4433', dish='Stracotto', price=25.5)]
```

Or call .sort on the list:

```
RC.sort(key=restaurant_price) # sort original list 
print(RC)
```

.sort:

```
In [20]: RC.sort(key=restaurant_price)

In [21]: RC
Out[21]: 
[Restaurant(name='Nobu', cuisine='Japanese', phone='335-4433', dish='Natto Temaki', price=5.5),
 Restaurant(name='Thai Dishes', cuisine='Thai', phone='334-4433', dish='Mee Krob', price=12.5),
 Restaurant(name='Nonna', cuisine='Italian', phone='355-4433', dish='Stracotto', price=25.5)]
```

To just get the names:

```
In [24]: [x.name for x in sorted(RC,key=restaurant_price)]
Out[24]: ['Nobu', 'Thai Dishes', 'Nonna']
```

without using an explicit for loop loop or zip:

```
from operator import itemgetter
print(list(map(itemgetter(0),sorted(RC,key=restaurant_price)))
['Nobu', 'Thai Dishes', 'Nonna']
```

Comment: would it not be `key=restaurant_price` without parenthesis?

Comment: When i do RC.sort(key=restaurant_price()) and then
print(RC), I get an error message of: restaurant_price() missing 1 required positional argument: 'restaurant'

Comment: @anonymousfox, no parens on restaurant_price

Comment: Ok, but how do i get it to print out just the list of restaurant names in order of least expensive dish to most expensive dish, not the list of all attributes with that restaurant?

Comment: how do you do it without using for loops or if statements?

Comment: there are no if's, what do you mean by no for loop?

Comment: how do you do it without "for x in"?

Comment: @anonymousfox, I cannot think of any way without using some kind of loop, is that a requirement?

Comment: You could `list(zip(*sorted(RC,key=restaurant_price)))[0]` but I would not recommend it.

Comment: yeah that's a requirement, and I can't use the zip.